# VBA code using "Cells(Rows.count).Row).End(xlUp)" fails after 263 iterations

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a Sub of the form:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then (+ code)
```

in conjunction with:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range ("A1" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

with the intention of copying data from a cell (e.g. A1) on Sheet1, which changes frequently, to a column (e.g. A:) on Sheet2.

This works fine for the first 263 iterations (it is always 263 regardless of the time intervals), but then on the 264th, instead of copying the next value to the next empty cell in the column, it continuously overwrites the value in cell A2. This is unfortunate, as I need to record at least 600 values.

I am using Excel 2013 under Windows 10.

Comment: You need to include the actual mechanism for looping - the code you have doesn't show where the error would be. Include the entire section of the Sub which contains the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Sheets("Sheet2").Range ("A" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).` ? I don't understand that "1" after the "A".

Comment: I agree with iDevlop, it should be just "A"

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Fetching `Cells(Rows.Count)` with only one parameter does not lead you to the bottom cell of column A, because `Cells()` will then count items horizontally before moving to next row. After some operations you are falling back to the already used area.

Comment: In the corrected code, where is the initial destination cell on the left-hand side of the assignment statement? (In my example, A1).

Comment: @A.Johnson as I understood your OP, you wanted to copy from Sheet1/A1 into Sheet2/first empty cell in column A. The above does that. I probably misunderstood you requirement.

Comment: Apologies, I gave A1 as an example. In the actual code, a number of origin cells are copied over between sheets. The values in P8, Q8, R8 etc. on Sheet1  are passed to various columns on Sheet2 whose topmost cell is C4, D4, E4 etc.

Comment: The above code corrects your mistake that occurs after 263 entries. If your Worksheet_Change event is written correctly but had only this error, as in the OP, I think it will work if you apply the (idea of) this correction. :)

Comment: It does indeed. The adapted code works perfectly. Part of me still wonders why the original code fails after 263 iterations. But life is short...

Comment: I said it in the answer, you were not fetching correctly the last cell of column A. You were using Cells(Rows.count) with only one parameter. This leads to row 63. when this falls into your used area, xlUp takes you back to row 1. OTOH, Cells(Cells(Rows.count, 1) leads to row 1,048,576, which with xlUp is guaranteed to take you to your last used row.